# Moving a text file in c# if it contains a value

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to move a file if it contains a certain string, Code below

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            //reads the file contents

                string MessageContents = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
                //checks if the textwords are present in the file
                foreach (string Keyword in textwords)
                {
                    //if they are file is moved to quarantine messages
                    if (MessageContents.Contains(Keyword))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            File.Move(file.FullName, File_quarantine);
                        }
                        catch (IOException cannot_Move_File)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("The process has failed: {0}", cannot_Move_File.ToString());
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                      //else it is moved To valid messages
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            File.Move(file.FullName, File_Valid);
                        }
                        catch (IOException cannot_Move_File)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("The process has failed: {0}", cannot_Move_File.ToString());
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However the process always fails with the error `A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

I am unsure as to why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You still have a lock on the file, because you opened a stream to it. Move your logic of moving the file out of the reading of the file. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You still have a lock on the file, because you opened a stream to it. Move your logic of moving the file out of the reading of the file.

This should produce the desired result;

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    String messageContents = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
    bool toQuarantine = textwords.Any(keyWord => messageContents.Contains(keyWord));

    try
    {
        File.Move(file.FullName, toQuarantine ? File_quarantine : File_Valid);
    }
    catch (IOException cannot_Move_File)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The process has failed: {0}", cannot_Move_File.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the message of the exception? (You did not specify previously)

Comment: The error I am getting is `System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` however the file does not exist in the destination folder i am trying to move it to

Comment: It might be because `File_quarantine` and `File_Valid` are always the same, so then it will fail on the 2nd file that has or doesn't have any keywords. If you don't mind overwriting files, you could first test if it exists and then remove it.

Comment: So for example, put a `for` statement within the `try` method for checking whether the file exists?

Comment: @bdg No you will have to either; specify unique-strings for each file, or delete the file before moving or use copy with overwrite and then delete instead of move.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a lock on the file.  You can't move it while you're reading it.

If the files are relatively small, you can use a technique like this:

```
String content = File.ReadAllText( filename );

// at this point, the file is not locked, unlike the 
// way it is in your question.  you are free to move it

foreach (String keyword in keywords) {
    if (content.Contains(keyword)) {
        // Move file
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: will the try and catch method I have used work where you specified `// Move File` I have edited the question to reflect your advice, however i am still getting the same error message